# How to handle a private remote dependency in a new R package?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, r-usethis

I am writing an R package (let's called it `new.package`) that needs to import functions from another private R package (let's called it `remote.private.package`). `remote.private.package` is a private package on a github private remote repository (let's assume at `github::username/remote_private_package`).

I have run the following line which adds a private remote dependency to the `new.package` DESCRIPTION file:

```
usethis::use_dev_package("remote.private.package", type = "Imports", remote = c("username/remote_private_package", auth_token = "my_github_auth_token"))
```

This is the content of the relevant section of the DESCRIPTION file, after running the above line:

```
    ...
Remotes: 
    username/remote_private_package,
    my_github_auth_token
Imports: 
    remote.private.package (>= 0.1.0),
    ...
```

However when i run `devtools::load_all()` i get the following console message:

```
ℹ Loading new.package
ℹ The package `remote.private.package` (>= 0.1.0) is required.
✖ Would you like to install it?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

Error: HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`username`) and repo name (`remote_private_package`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

I am sure that the info is correct because when i run:

```
remotes::install_github("username/remote_private_package", auth_token = "my_github_auth_token")
library(remote.private.package)
```

The package is installed and loaded correctly.

What are the best practices to handle packages with private remote repository dependencies?